# sqlalchemy declaring the same model twice

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy on a flask project. I need to use a model that i have already declared in a different module for the project. Is there any effect to declaring it again or is the best option to import it from the module?

Comment: normally I would say, import the model.

Comment: Will create a global models module to make it easier for this for all the models i think i will be using on the entire project

Comment: Without showing code and your current way of working it is really hard to respond and add value to the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to declare the model if it already exists in the database? Sqlalchemy allows you to read the metadata from the db and use it as a table for example

```
metadata = db.MetaData(bind=engine)
your_table = db.Table('your_table', metadata, autoload=True)
```

Comment: I did not know about this but it seems to have solved my problems. I was creating models for tables that exist

Comment: Common "mistake". I won't pretend declaring your models explicitly had no advantages - but for legacy databases, just taking the model from the db usually does the job. Also useful if developers are still in progress of changing the table in the database and can't be asked to keep "your code" (models) up-to-date.

Comment: Makes sense, this will make life easier